# Change user's profile text

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I was reading this [comment](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5037/fair-to-vtc-for-trolling#comment14652_5038) and viewed the [user's profile](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/77797/daniel-grover), the quote they've attached to their profile is a bit rude. Do we mind that?

If we don't want that, could an admin please update it to something nicer?

Comment: Here's the semi-official stance on what should be allowed in profiles: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/260884

Comment: Also related: "[Why is the f word still allowed in profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31197/why-is-the-f-word-still-allowed-in-profiles)", "[Is offensive and rude language directed at you allowed in your profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286180/is-offensive-and-rude-language-directed-at-you-allowed-in-your-profile)", and "[Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)"

Comment: Interesting notes David, thanks for the feedback. Seems the community disagrees, so the message stays

Comment: I would agree that the message should stay, but it's certainly a worthwhile question to ask.

Comment: Hehe, seems it was my comment :) IMO it is rude but as David pointed out it's their profile and there seems to be no active restriction for such (spam user profiles are a different case I guess). That user is now disengaged on the Network, after his episode of negative and rude "contributions" here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bit rude, and if it were in a post or comment gratuitously it'd be flag-worthy, but in general, SE lets people use their profiles as they like so long as they aren't *blatantly* offensive.  The [official guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/162102) includes the following:

> 1. Generally speaking, your "about me" is just that—what you want to share with the world, and we try to allow users a good bit of freedom there.
> 2. However, in the rare cases where what's there is likely to be truly offensive to large groups of seemingly reasonable people, we may not allow it.

And this expansion:

> We will probably not allow:
>
> - Most terms or statements that directly malign (non-famous) individuals
> - Any terms or statements that imply something derogatory about a racial, ethnic, religious, gender or sexual orientation group
> - Things that are likely to be strong emotional triggers (like rape, suicide, etc.)
> - Statements that appear to be demonstrably libelous
>
> We will probably allow:
>
> - Things groups or individuals would vehemently disagree with, but don't seem to directly malign them.

The text in the profile in question is: "I dun hacked into your shit, bitch!"  Mild profanity has been allowed to stand in profiles before and it doesn't appear to be a specific attack against a person or group, so meh.  If that's how this user wants to present himself to the world, it's on him.

Thanks for raising the concern.