# Not entirely sure how to react to a question which seems a little too out-there

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question I'm referring to:  [Getting training on a job with a child on the way](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/128452/getting-training-on-a-job-with-a-child-on-the-way)

This *might* be a legitimate question, but there's enough red flags for me:

- Kid on the way (as in, by the time we're done pontificating this question, the kid will be here in all likelihood)
- Girlfriend still attending classes in college (dunno about this one)
- Looking for job but job training requires OP to move away from family (may boil down to personal preference than anything concrete or answerable)

The question seems a little bit too out-there for my tastes.  The circumstance with the OP's family is not uncommon, but it isn't like these are *unknowns*.  The OP seems to want to delegate life and circumstance decision making to the community, and this just doesn't *feel* right to me.

What do we do in this case?  Should this question remain open?  How should I react to questions like this in the future?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fair to VTC for trolling](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5037/fair-to-vtc-for-trolling)

Answer (score 3):

If a question smells wrong to you, then don't interact with it, or with other people interacting with it - there's usually plenty of other questions and answers to deal with instead.  Or you can vote to close the question if you feel that one of the close reasons is appropriate.

Or you can leave a comment asking for more clarification.  Many people here don't have English as a first/strong language and may need some coaxing to make sense of their given situation.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems perfectly legitimate too me, though it is borderline on-topic as it's currently phrased.

For how to handle questions that you suspect of trolling, we have a number of meta questions on that under the [trolling](/questions/tagged/trolling) tag. The [general guidance](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5052/16983) is to vote based on the content of the question and don't assume the motives of the asker.